# Jquery syntax and regex operators

Tags: jquery, regex

Can some one explain what the || operator mean in the following line - does it mean OR. If it means OR how does one interpret the line because it doesn't make sense:

```
d = a.attr("data-template") || "<% remainingChars %> characters left"
```

Below is code from which its taken

```
$("[maxlength]").each(function (ind, elem) {
    var b = $(this), 
        a = b.parent(".form-group").find(".caption"),
        d = a.attr("data-template") || "<% remainingChars %> characters left";
```

And the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <small class="caption" data-template="<% remainingChars %> characters left">
           150 characters left
    </small>
    <input type="text">                    
</div>
```

What does the second replace part of the following regex do and what does {{maxCount}} mean?

```
c = d.replace(/<% remainingChars %>/gi, g()).replace(/{{maxCount}}/gi, j);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

`d = a.attr("data-template") || "<% remainingChars %> characters left"`

means: if `a.attr("data-template")` is truthy then assign its value to `d` otherwise `d` should equal `"<% remainingChars %> characters left"`

It could be written as:

```
if (a.attr("data-template")) {
  d = a.attr("data-template");
} else {
  d = "<% remainingChars %> characters left";
}
```

or

```
d = a.attr("data-template") ? a.attr("data-template") : "<% remainingChars %> characters left"
```

Use of `<% remainingChars %>` and `{{maxCount}}` suggest some kind of templating "language" although it seems it's a mix of Handlebars/Mustache ({{}}) and underscore, EJS... (possibly) (<% %>).